# Definition of the set of definitions.

Tags: logic, set-theory

A formula $\varphi[x]$ with one free variable $x$ in the language of sets is a *definition in ZF* if $ZF \vdash \exists y \forall z(\varphi[z] \longleftrightarrow z = y)$.

Is there a definition in ZF of the (meta-)set of Gödel numbers of definitions in ZF?

I suspect it isn't but I can't find a contradiction in assuming this existence. 
One idea would be to find a trick to define the truth of sentences in the language of set theory using the definition of the fact of being a definition, but I don't see how.

Comment: Your question asks, in short, we can define a class of definable sets?

Comment: [A theorem by Hamkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/) might be relevant.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon: Yes, I say the (meta-)set because if that "class" is definable, then it is a set by comprehension.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon: (I realize now that both comments are from you) Thanks, i'll try to see if this helps.

Comment: Oh, I feel I confuse definitions to definable sets...

Comment: I doubt it. Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of truth comes to mind. Let $[S]$ be the Godel number of the sentence $ S.$ (A sentence is a formula with no free variables).  There cannot exist a formula $\pi$ in one free variable such that  $\pi [(S)]\iff S$ holds for every $S$....  We can define the set  $T$ of all Godel numbers of the form $[\;\exists!y\;(\psi (y)].$ What you are asking for is a formula  $\pi$ in 1 free variable such that $\pi (U) \iff U=\{n\in T:  ZF\vdash n^*\}$ where $n^*$ is a sentence of the form $\exists! y\;(\theta (y)$  whose Godel number is $n.$

Comment: Continued from previous comment:  We would then have a truth-formula    in ZF, for all sentences of the form $\exists!y\;\phi(y),$ namely   $S\iff (\;[S]\in T\land \pi ([S])\;).$ If we  included sentences of every form we would be contradicted by Tarski's theorem. But (it just occurred to me) any sentence $W$ is equivalent  to  $\exists! y\;(\forall z \; (z\not \in y\land W)\;).$  So we would have a truth-formula for all sentences, which is precisely contrary to Tarski's theorem,

Comment: @user254665: That trick of $\exists ! y (\forall z(z \notin y \wedge W))$ is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find, thanks! You can post your comment as an answer I you want, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm tired. Feel free to post it as your own answer if you like. The theorem by Tarski must be in many books. In "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs"  by Kenneth Kunen, it's in Chapter 1, Section 14, following Theorem 14.2..... Is it permitted to  "accept" your own answer to your Q?

Comment: @Yes it is. (There's actually a valid proof of the theorem (of the diagonal lemma actually) on Wikipedia,) Thanks for your help.

Comment: As user21820's answer says, there is no difficulty at all in defining things involving provability, as you want to do here.  It seems you may be confusing provability in ZF with truth in the actual universe, which is not definable.  That is, you would not be able to define the set of $\varphi$ such that there exists exactly one $x$ such that $\varphi[x]$.  But that is very different from the set of $\varphi$ such that _ZF proves_ there exists exactly one such $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yep. And it's not so easy to even talk about "truth in the actual universe", simply because there is no way to even justify such a thing, not to say refer to it, without working in a system that already has access to some fixed universe of the smaller system (which wouldn't be the universe of that outer system either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um just let $D = \{ φ : \text{$φ$ is a $1$-parameter formula over ZF} \land \text{ZF} \vdash \exists! x ( φ[x] )\}$. Then $D$ is the set you are looking for. You would not be able to get a contradiction from this unless your meta-system is inconsistent.

If ZF is inconsistent, then ZF proves every sentence, and any reasonable meta-system can see that, and so $D$ would be the set of all $1$-parameter formulae. However, if ZF is consistent, it may still be $Σ_1$-unsound and think that itself is inconsistent, in which case $D$ is again the set of all $1$-parameter formulae if you are using ZF as your meta-system.

Comment: Thank you, I had misunderstood the théorème of the undefinability.

Comment: @nombre: You're welcome!